# Drop Down Menu In Python calling information from files

Tags: python, tkinter

So I need a drop down menu, where the user picks his/her client, and it returns information about that client.

lets say i have a file:

```
["client1", "client2", "client3"]
```

and I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

with open('ubclientlistvars.txt', 'r') as clients:
    clients = (clients.readlines())


variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("Choose Client")

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, clients)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

how would I draw the clients from the file into the drop down menu?
When I run this code, i get these two options:
`Choose Client` and `{["client1", "client2", "client3"]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually parse that file.  If the file contents are what you posted, then `readlines()` is just returning a single line of text.  It does not magically convert the file contents into a Python object.  Suppose the file was:

```
client1
client2
client3
```

Then you could use something like `clients = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]` to get a proper list of clients and can pass them to `OptionMenu`:

```
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *clients)
```

If you cannot change the file format then you will need to clean up the input before displaying it...

```
import re
data = f.read()  # ["client1", "client2", "client3"]
data = re.sub('["\[\]]', '', data)  # remove the ", [, and ] characters
clients = data.split(',')  # split the list of clients on the comma
```